Threshold on GGH Signature Scheme
I make an implementation of GGH Signature Scheme in python. I am trying to find the best threshold for the verification step. I want the threshold to be big enough so that verification always succeeds but small enough so that forgery (using Babai's Agorithm) is difficult. For example, when I used as threshold the norm of R_inverse divided by 2 (R is the private basis), I noticed that the signatures were far smaller than the threshold.
